# I'm A Mighty Tool

Tags: riddle

> I keep my head tucked away inside,
>
> A nice clean place for me to hide.
>
> I'll pop right out when there's a tale to tell,
>
> And when you're done go back in my shell.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Can be

> Pen

I keep my head tucked away inside,
A nice clean place for me to hide.

> While not using, its cap is on

I'll pop right out when there's a tale to tell,

> When there is something to write

And when you're done go back in my shell.

> When writing is over

Title:

> Well it is said to be mightier than sword

Comment: A great answer, kudos :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this may be a stretch but I think it's

> the titular answer. A mighty tool.

I keep my head tucked away inside,

> A tool keeps their head in their own world

A nice clean place for me to hide.

> And doesn't bother them-self with, or likely doesn't understand, the unpleasantness of the situations they're involved in

I'll pop right out when there's a tale to tell,

> You draw me into your world when you want to use, often through my effect on others (telling tales, for instance)

And when you're done go back in my shell.

> In the end, I still don't know the purpose of the plot, or even the existence of a plot itself, and I return to my little world.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a

> penknife

The reference to head is more literal when thinking of the

> screwdriver blades

but could be taken metaphorically on models which don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

> Army Knife

I keep my head tucked away inside,

A nice clean place for me to hide.

> always closed unless its needed

I'll pop right out when there's a tale to tell,

And when you're done go back in my shell.

> right part of knife opened when needed and close right after.

Comment: What about the tale?

Comment: When its required or there is purpose then it serves, means it tells her tale.

Comment: I have not heard that *it* tells her tale when it is used...

Comment: I guess you didn't read my answer that begins with "Seems like" not "It is" that means possibility.

Comment: "Seems like" means that you are not sure if it really is, how is that on-topic with the discussion?

Comment: >"Seems like" means that you are not sure< -this is true

Comment: Is it a requirement here to be sure before posting anything?